# How can I recognize the Zulu time zone in Java DateUtils.parseDate?

Tags: java, date, parsing, timezone

I have dates in the format `2008-12-23T00:00:00Z`. This look a lot like a [ISO 8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) with a Zulu (UTC) timezone. I though the following code would parse it (using [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateFormatUtils.html#ISO_DATETIME_TIME_ZONE_FORMAT)) :

```
String pattern = DateFormatUtils.ISO_DATETIME_TIME_ZONE_FORMAT.getPattern();
Date d = DateUtils.parseDate(dateToParse, new String[] { pattern });
```

If I take the same pattern (`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ`) but remove the timezone, it works.

Do you know how I can recognize the Zulu timezone ? I have access only to Java 1.4 and Jakarta commons-lang. No [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for me yet ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bug in commons-lang's `FastDateFormat`. Tell them about it, and you should get a fix eventually. Till then you could try to preprocess the dates and replace 'Z' with '+00'

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. I wont be able to upgrade to a new version of the commons-lang before a few years ;-) but it might help somebody else ...

Answer (score 48):

I think commons-lang is using java's built-in DateFormat or SimpleDateFormat which throws a ParseException for your date. If all your input strings end with the trailing Z, you could use this:

```
java.text.DateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
// explicitly set timezone of input if needed
df.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("Zulu"));
java.util.Date date = df.parse("2008-12-23T00:00:00Z");
```

Comment: +1... I always have to look this crap up when I'm not using JodaTime