# ISO 8601 String to Date/Time object in Android

Tags: java, android, parsing, iso8601

I have a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format that contains the date/time returned from a web service like so:

```
String dtStart = "2010-10-15T09:27:37Z"
```

How do I get this into an object such as Time or Date? I initially want to output it in a different format, but will need to do other stuff with it later (i.e. maybe use in a different format).

Cheers

Comment: Similar: [*Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2201925/642706)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

```
String dtStart = "2010-10-15T09:27:37Z";  
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");  
try {  
    Date date = format.parse(dtStart);  
    System.out.println(date);  
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

This is what you are looking for. There is [existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424522/parsing-datetime-in-java) about this problem.

Comment: Thanks very much, I did look on here and via Google, but never found anything that did what I wanted

Comment: To all, supported date formats are: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: If you are having milliseconds too then this format worked for me   `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`

Answer (score 7):

This question was asked in 2010, and back then it was correct that either `SimpleDateFormat` or Joda-Time would be the tools you should use. It’s quite a while ago now. Today use

```
    Instant iStart = Instant.parse(dtStart);
```

Yes, it’s this simple. Your string is in ISO 8601 format, and the classes from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, parse ISO 8601 without any explicit formatter. `Instant` is just one of those classes.

### Edit: Question: requires android API 26 - what about supporting older versions?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: requires android API 26 - what about supporting older versions?

Comment: @ElJazouli Thank you for the question. I tried to cover that already, but I am aware that many readers miss this part. How can I make it clearer? I edited the relevant header, but maybe that’s not enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Java's SimpleDateFormat parse method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,java.text.ParsePosition%29) or use [JodaTime's DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forPattern%28java.lang.String%29) to create a DateTimeFormatter and [parse to a DateTime object](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseDateTime%28java.lang.String%29) accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you use current `java.time` or `threetenbp` simply parse it like this:

```
ZonedDateTime dt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dtStart);
```

Now you can access date and time values such as year, month, hour, etc.