# Convert date and time to String, ANDROID

Tags: android, date, time

I have date and time this format

```
$date:2013-02-19T11:20:16.393Z
```

and I can convert normal format for example:

```
19.02.2013 11:20:16
```

Comment: I don't see a question

Comment: It's a good start to search around a little bit using the keywords similar to "Java" "format date"

Comment: Likely duplicate of: [*ISO 8601 String to Date/Time object in Android*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3941357/642706)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$date:2013-02-19T11:20:16.393Z
```

So your actual format is `ISO 8601`
For your goal you need to use some **DateFormatter** with proper pattern and work is done.

At first you need to rewrite your date into pattern so

`19.02.2013 11:20:16` is equal to `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss`

So now you need to use formatter for example [`SimpleDateFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) that perform converting.

**Pseudocode:**

```
String source = "2013-02-19T11:20:16.393Z";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date formatted = null;
formatted = formatter.parse(source);
String formattedString = formatted.toString();
```