# Android: Compare time in this format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` to the current moment

Tags: android, date, datetime, time

I want to get the current time on the device in the format: 2013-10-17 15:45:01 ?

The server sends me the date of an object in the format above as a string.  Now i want to get the phones current time and then check if there is a difference of say more than 5 minutes?

So A:  How can i get the devices current time in this fomat: `2013-10-17 15:45:01`

B how can I work out the difference between the two.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [SampleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: You do not want to do A, since comparing string date times will be a nightmare.  You want to convert the server string into a date time and then compare with the current phone time.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941357/string-to-date-time-object-in-android/3941395#3941395

Comment: @YeLinAung No, never use the terrible legacy classes `SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar`, or `Date`. They were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the unanimous adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62681240/642706) for example code.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to specify the pattern you want:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date())
```

However, if you just want to know whether the time difference is within a certain threshold, you should probably just compare long values.  If your threshold is 5 minutes, then this is `5 * 60 * 1000` milliseconds so you can use the same `SimpleDateFormat` by calling it's `parse` method and check the long values.

*Example:*

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse("2013-10-13 14:54:03").getTime()
```

Comment: You should specify a locale, e.g. `Locale.US`, as a second parameter in the `new SimpleDateFormat(...)` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

`Date currentDate = new Date();` will initialize a new date with the current time. In addition, [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941357/string-to-date-time-object-in-android/3941395#3941395) the server provided time and take the difference.

```
String objectCreatedDateString = "2013-10-17 15:45:01";  
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
Date objectCreatedDate = null;
Date currentDate = new Date();
try 
{objectCreatedDate = format.parse(objectCreatedDateString);} 
catch (ParseException e) 
{Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());}
int timeDifferential;
if (objectCreatedDate != null)
    timeDifferential = objectCreatedDate.getMinutes() - currentDate.getMinutes();
```

Comment: You don't really have to supply System.currentTimeMillis() to java.util.Date constructor - it's automatically initialized with curent time. But you must specify new operator.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.between(  // Calculate time elapsed between two moments.
    LocalDateTime  // Represent a date with time-of-day but lacking the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.
        .parse( "2013-10-17 15:45:01".replace( " " , "T" ) )
        .atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )  // Returns an `OffsetDateTime` object.
        .toInstant() ,  // Returns an `Instant` object.
    Instant.now() // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC.
)
.toMinutes()
> 5
```

## java.time

The other Answers are outdated, using terrible classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Parse your incoming string.

```
String input = "2013-10-17 15:45:01" ;
```

Modify the input to comply with ISO 8601. I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about the ISO 8601 standard.

```
String inoutModified = input.replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

Parse as a `LocalDateTime` because this input lacks an indicator of the intended offset or time zone.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

I assume that input was intended to represent a moment as seen in UTC, with an offset of zero hours minutes seconds. If so, educate the publisher of your data about appending a `Z` on the end to so indicate, per ISO 8601.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Extract an object of the simpler class, `Instant`. This class is always in UTC.

```
Instant then = odt.toInstant() ;
```

Get current moment as seen in UTC.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

Calculate the difference.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( then , now ) ;
```

Get duration as total whole minutes.

```
long minutes = d.toMinutes() ;
```

Test.

```
if ( minutes > 5 ) { … }
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Answer (score 1):

Use SimpleDateFromat Class

```
DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
dateFormatter.format(date);
```

Also check this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you can ask the server to send you an RFC3339 compliant date/time string, then Here is a simple answer to both of your questions:

```
public String getClientTime() {
    Time clientTime = new  Time().setToNow();
    return clientTime.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
}

public int diffClientAndServerTime(String svrTimeStr) {
    Time svrTime = new Time();
    svrTime.parse3339(svrTimeStr);

    Time clientTime = new  Time();
    clientTime.setToNow();
    return svrTime.compare( svrTime, clientTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying this and finally this worked for me:

```
fun getTimeAgo(dateString: String): String {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val then = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString
            .replace(" ","T"))
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toInstant()
        val now = LocalDateTime.now().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant()
        val diff = Duration.between(then, now).seconds
        return when {
            diff < 60 -> "$diff seconds ago"
            diff < 3600 -> "${diff / 60} minutes ago"
            diff < 86400 -> "${diff / 3600} hours ago"
            else -> "${diff / 86400} days ago"
        }
    } else {
        return dateString
    }
}
```