# How to solve java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date?

Tags: java, date, date-format

I'm trying to convert this to a readable format however, keep getting `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-11-18T11:13:43.838Z" (at offset 23)`

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.US);
try {
    Date date1 = df.parse("2016-11-18T11:13:43.838Z");

    DateFormat outputFormatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    String output1 = outputFormatter1.format(date1); //
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I read about adding locale as other SO answers suggested but it is still not working.

Comment: Put the Z in single quotes in your `SimpleDateFormat`. Like this: `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");`

Comment: you are missing the timezone....

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ He does have a timezone. `Z` is the zero timezone, equivalent to `+0000`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ISO 8601 String to Date/Time object in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941357/iso-8601-string-to-date-time-object-in-android)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are parsing a string that is not a correct representation of that pattern, you are missing the TimeZone... something like: `-0600`

example:

```
Date date1 = df.parse("2016-11-18T11:13:43.838-0600Z");
```

here is the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more info....

your code should look like:

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    try {
        Date date1 = df.parse("2016-11-18T11:13:43.838-0600Z");
        DateFormat outputFormatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String output1 = outputFormatter1.format(date1); //
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked. The solution was to change how the back-end is saving date so I can format it on allowable patterns by SimpleDateFormat. Unless someone can provide a solution without changing the value of date returned by the api call, I think this is the best answer.

Comment: @Woppi -0600 is not the same as Z (=+0000). So if you change the input like that via string preprocessing you will get another result. If your JVM is too old (before Java-7 no support for X-pattern) then you should rather replace "Z" by "+0000" (or even "+00:00").

Answer (score 6):

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone) the `Z` in your format string indicates an RFC 822 time zone e.g. +01:00. You need to parse a ISO 8601 Time zone (the `Z` in your input string indicating UTC timezone). You configure that with `X`:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", Locale.US);
```

Comment: Hello, I tried X but getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X' at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validatePatternCharacter(SimpleDateFormat.java:314)". BTW, I am using this in Android app and I just realize the pattern saved on our mongodb is not supported in android https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

Reading the Javadoc for [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), I found that using `Z` for timezone is very strict. It will not recognize `"Z"` as zulu, it only accepts numeric timezone offsets.
You might want to try `X` instead, which accept `"Z"` according to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this format

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

Comment: Incorrect answer. The `Z` in the string to parse is a UTC offset of 0. When you ignore it, you aren’t getting the correct time.

Comment: Yes, correct solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50481735/5772882) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43737317/5772882).