# How to convert UTC Date String and remove the T and Z in Java?

Tags: java, java-7, utc, datetime-parsing, parseexception

Am using Java 1.7.

Trying to convert:

```
2018-05-23T23:18:31.000Z
```

into

```
2018-05-23 23:18:31
```

DateUtils class:

```
public class DateUtils {

    public static String convertToNewFormat(String dateStr) throws ParseException {
        TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        sdf.setTimeZone(utc);
        Date convertedDate = sdf.parse(dateStr);
        return convertedDate.toString();
    }
}
```

When trying to use it:

```
String convertedDate = DateUtils.convertToNewFormat("2018-05-23T23:18:31.000Z");
System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

Get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-05-23T23:22:16.000Z"
   at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
   at com.myapp.utils.DateUtils.convertToNewFormat(DateUtils.java:7)
```

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Is there an easier way to do is (e.g. Apache Commons lib)?

Comment: While you can remove `T`, `Z` is the offset and should be parsed as such, or incorrect results are most likely. As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to your project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Coincidentally I just yesterday wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50481735/5772882) that shows the correct,  modern, good and simple way to parse your string.

Comment: Your input date-time string is in UTC (denoted by the `Z` suffix). Do you want your output in your local time zone? Or which time zone?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this. You have to use one pattern for parsing and another for formatting.

```
public static String convertToNewFormat(String dateStr) throws ParseException {
    TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    SimpleDateFormat destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    sourceFormat.setTimeZone(utc);
    Date convertedDate = sourceFormat.parse(dateStr);
    return destFormat.format(convertedDate);
}
```

Comment: Same code in kotlin : val utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
val sourceFormat =  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
val destFormat =  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
sourceFormat.setTimeZone(utc)
val convertedDate : Date = sourceFormat.parse(dateStr)
val result = destFormat.format(convertedDate)

Answer (score 13):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "2018-05-23T23:18:31.000Z" )                // Parse this String in standard ISO 8601 format as a `Instant`, a point on the timeline in UTC. The `Z` means UTC.
.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )                                // Change from `Instant` to the more flexible `OffsetDateTime`.
.format(                                                   // Generate a String representing the value of this `OffsetDateTime` object.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" )   // Specify a formatting pattern as desired.
)                                                          // Returns a `String` object.
```

> 2018-05-23 23:18:31

## ISO 8601

Your input string is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

The `T` separates the year-month-day portion from the hour-minute-second. The `Z` is pronounced `Zulu` and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. The Apache `DateUtils` is also no longer needed, as you will find its functionality in *java.time* as well.

Parse that input string as a `Instant` object. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
String input = "2018-05-23T23:18:31.000Z" ;
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

To generate a string in another format, we need a more flexible object. The `Instant` class is meant to be a basic building block. Let`s convert it to a` OffsetDateTime`, using UTC itself as the specified offset-from-UTC.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Define a formatting pattern to match your desired output.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ) ;
String output = odt.format( f ) ;
```

Tip: Consider using `DateTimeFormatter::ofLocalized…` methods to automatically localize the String generation per some `Locale` rather than hard-coding a formatting pattern.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 5):

For others without Java 1.7 Restrictions:

Since Java 1.8 you can do it using `LocalDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` from the package `java.time`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sourceDateTime           = "2018-05-23T23:18:31.000Z";
    DateTimeFormatter sourceFormat  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    DateTimeFormatter targetFormat  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    LocalDateTime dateTime          = LocalDateTime.parse(sourceDateTime, sourceFormat);
    String formatedDateTime         = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).format(targetFormat);
    System.out.println(formatedDateTime);
}
```

EDIT: (see Comments)

Quote from the Oracle Java documentation of [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html):

> LocalDateTime is an immutable date-time object that represents a
>   date-time, often viewed as year-month-day-hour-minute-second. Other
>   date and time fields, such as day-of-year, day-of-week and
>   week-of-year, can also be accessed. Time is represented to nanosecond
>   precision. For example, the value "2nd October 2007 at
>   13:45.30.123456789" can be stored in a LocalDateTime.
>
> This class does not store or represent a time-zone. Instead, it is a
>   description of the date, as used for birthdays, combined with the
>   local time as seen on a wall clock. It cannot represent an instant on
>   the time-line without additional information such as an offset or
>   time-zone.

the OP is asking to JUST parsing an Input String to a date-time (as year-month-day-hour-minute-second) and the Documentation says

> LocalDateTime ... represents a date-time, often viewed as
>   year-month-day-hour-minute-second

so no important information are lost here. And the part `dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))` returns a `ZonedDateTime` so the ZimeZone is handled at this point again if the user needs to work with the timezone ...etc.

so don't try to force users to use the "One and Only" solution you present in your answer.

Comment: Using `LocalDateTime` means you are throwing away important information, with nothing gained.

Comment: This will work nicely in Java 1.7 too when you add [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to your project. You don’t need a formatter for the input. `Instant.parse` and the one-arg `OffsetDateTime.parse` will parse the source string without any explicit formatter.

Comment: @BasilBourque See my Edit!. @ OleV.V: if a user ask such simple Question, so its better to give him/her the straight and informative Answer, so he/she can understand the functionality. After that he/she could compare other Classes/methods available out there. You said "you don't need a formatter for the input" this is only true if the input is always with this "standard format", otherwise you need a formatter, so i mentioned it in my Answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html).

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [Home Page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-05-23T23:18:31.000Z")
     .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH));
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Aow4T1)

Note that you do not need a custom `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the date-time string, 2018-05-23T23:18:31.000Z as it is already in the default pattern used by `ZonedDateTime`. The modern date-time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Some helpful answers using `java.time` API:

1. [`'Z'` is not the same as `Z`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67953075/10819573).
2. [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).
3. I [prefer u to y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908827/kotlin-datetimeparseexception/65928023#65928023) with a `DateTimeFormatter`.

---

### For the sake of completeness

For the sake of completeness, given below is a solution using the legacy date-time API:

```
DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", Locale.ENGLISH);
parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date dateTime = parser.parse("2018-05-23T23:18:31.000Z");

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
formatter.setTimeZone(parser.getTimeZone());
String formattedDateTimeString = formatter.format(dateTime);
System.out.println(formattedDateTimeString);
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/9wlOrX)

Answer (score 0):

`YYYY` does not match with year part. In java 7 you need `yyyy`.

For `T`, use `'T'` to match it

You're also missing the faction of millsecond part: `.SSS`

Try this:

```
String dateStr="2018-05-23T23:18:31.000Z";
TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
sdf.setTimeZone(utc);
Date convertedDate = sdf.parse(dateStr);
convertedDate.toString();
```

Comment: Thank you Manh, but this prints out as May 23 11:18:31 PDT 2018 - I just want it to be 2018-05-23 23:18:31

Comment: You must provide a format to it. `SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'); return sdf2.format(convertedDate);`

Comment: Tried that before responding to you earlier and it still gave a ParseException.

Comment: It works as intended. Which part did you stuck at? I have a typo at above `SimpleDateFormat`, it needs 4 `y` instead of `yyy`

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin and using ThreeTenABP,

```
fun getIsoString(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int): String {
    val localTime = ZonedDateTime.of(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("Z"))

    val utcTime = localTime.toOffsetDateTime().withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)

    val isoString = utcTime.toInstant().toString() // 1940-15-12T00:00:00Z

    val formattedIsoString = val formattedIsoString =
        Instant.parse(isoString)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .format(DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")) // 'T' in quotes so that it is retained.

    return formattedIsoString
}

// print it
print(getIsoString(1940, 15, 12)) // 1940-15-12T00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below the idea.
I am not an expert in JAVA but I did it in javascript/node.js

```
import * as momentTimeZone from 'moment-timezone';

let d = new Data(); // d = '2018-05-23T23:18:31.000Z'; or we can take this date
let finalOutput = momentTimeZone(d).tz(this.locationService.locationTimeZone).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log('Result: ', finalOutput); // Result: "2018-05-23 23:18:31";
```

It also works with `moment.js`.
Here is more about [format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).