# how to convert UTC date-time into ISO 8601 format in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, iso8601

I want to format a UTC date-time in a specific ISO 8601 format like **2020-02-28T14:10:23+00:00** but not **2020-02-28T14:10:23Z**. I don't want Z at the end but +00:00. I tried all the formats in [simpleDateFormat doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone) and no format seems to give the above-mentioned one.

I know both represents same time irrespective of the format but it needs to be formatted like that for backward compatibility reasons.

Here is the java code that I tried,

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

It could be achieved by replacing z with +00:00 in the formatted string but it doesn't seems to be a good option.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, It is a correct format. you could refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50498949/how-to-convert-utc-date-string-and-remove-the-t-and-z-in-java ?

Comment: Maybe https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME ? It looks like the format you ask for.

Comment: @user85421 thanks for your comment but it gives result like 2020-02-28T14:10:23+0000 without : in between

Comment: @GPI thanks for the reference but i have tried DateTimeFormatter and no format seems to have this

Comment: @Shubham I think that question itself is irrelevant to this

Comment: @Ajithkumar_sekar It's doesn't have it because Z is how UTC is marked in ISO 8601.

Comment: @akuzminykh no, it could be represented like that https://imgur.com/hsWHOJ6

Comment: @Ajithkumar_sekar I mean, you can, but Z is the usual way. That's why all the default ```DateTimeFormatter``` have it done with Z. Btw. @user85421 has the answer.

Comment: You should **not** use the obsolete `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. Use the newer Date and Time API (from the `java.time` package).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) of `DateTimeFormatter`

> *Offset X and x*: This formats the offset based on the number of pattern letters. One letter outputs just the hour, such as '+01', unless the minute is non-zero in which case the minute is also output, such as '+0130'. Two letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon, such as '+0130'. **Three letters outputs the hour and minute, with a colon, such as '+01:30'**. Four letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, without a colon, such as '+013015'. Five letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, with a colon, such as '+01:30:15'. Six or more letters throws IllegalArgumentException. Pattern letter 'X' (upper case) will output 'Z' when the offset to be output would be zero, whereas **pattern letter 'x' (lower case) will output '+00', '+0000', or '+00:00'**.

Try with `xxx` like in:

```java
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx").format(ZonedDateTime.now())
```

which returns something like

> ```
> 2020-02-28T12:42:30+00:00
> ```

<sup>Based on Java version 13, tested with `jshell` OpenJDK 13; `DateTimeFormatter` is available in Java 8 or later</sup>