# Java Date Format:YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:ss.xxx-xxxx

Tags: java, datetime

I am having trouble getting this following date in java pojo, when I parse using below date using below format I am getting only

INPUT: `2012-05-07T12:46:16.611-0500`

---

```
public static String formatDate(Date date) {
    return date == null ? null : 
                          FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD_T_HH_MM_SS_DOTXXX.format(date);
}
```

---

OUTPUT: `2012-05-07T12:46:16.06`

EXCPECTED: `2012-05-07T12:46:16.611-0500`

How to write date format equivalent to ABOVE given date in java?
to get full date

Comment: What is `FORMAT_YYYY_M_D_T_HH_MM_SS_DOTXXX`?

Comment: Input and expected output are same.

Comment: something like [how to convert UTC date-time into ISO 8601 format in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60451547/85421) ?

Comment: Well, you have two `MM` in your format; the second should be `mm`.

Comment: To get better (if any) help [edit] your question and include [mcve] (in short example which is minimal - without any unrelated things like GUI, reading data from user when example data can be provided in code; complete - so we could copy-paste it to our machines and run it without any modifications; reproducable - it should generate precisely same problem you are claiming in the question).

Comment: Don't use `Date`, that's obsolete. Use classes from `java.time` instead.