# How to parse UTC timestamp of format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS+ZZZZ

Tags: java, scala, timestamp, utc, timestamp-with-timezone

I have timestamp as `2020-12-03T05:35:59.398+0000` in `String` format being recieved in a streaming batch.

I want only `2020-12-03 05:35:59` as `java.sql.Timestamp` instance in order to be able to compare it with other `Timestamp` instance.

Getting following error with `Timestamp.valueOf()` function:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException : Text '2020-12-03T05:35:59.398+0000' could not be parsed at index 23
```

I tried the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50498949/how-to-convert-utc-date-string-and-remove-the-t-and-z-in-java) , and conversion did happen but the time was changed to `2020-12-03 11:05:59`

I have tried changing between the formats given [here](https://help.sumologic.com/03Send-Data/Sources/04Reference-Information-for-Sources/Timestamps%2C-Time-Zones%2C-Time-Ranges%2C-and-Date-Formats) but still no solution.

Is there even a format for timestamp with wierd `+` in between `398+0000`?

Comment: comments are welcome for negative vote on the question

Comment: Please check now after edit.

Comment: Can you avoid using `Timestamp`? That class is poorly and confusingly designed and long outdated. If you tell us where you got the other `Timestamp` from, we may be able to offer better alternatives substituting with (or converting to) classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) like for example `OffsetDateTIme`.

Comment: Other Timestamp to which I am comparing to is also String type. Basically I am using Timestamp.valueOf only to convert String to TImestamp.

Comment: It sounds like you have 2 dates of type `String` and you want to convert them to a Date/Time type in order to invoke comparison methods on them. Is that correct? If so I'd recommend using the `java.time` library and stay away from `java.sql.Timestamp`, which is a thin wrapper around the old and outdated `java.util.Date`.

Comment: *but the time was changed to `2020-12-03 11:05:59`*. No, it was not changed. It was just printed in your time zone (probably Asia/Kolkata).

Comment: @OleV.V. If it so then how can I check the Time Zone from Timestap and update it accordingly?

Comment: @jwvh Yeah. I am comparing timestamps

Comment: Cant do much about problem X as it is an input from raw unstructured data. So problem Y only needs to be enhanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

```
    DateTimeFormatter isoFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx");
    DateTimeFormatter sqlTimestampFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .toFormatter();
    
    String aTimestampString = "2020-12-03T05:35:59.398+0000";
    String anotherTimestampString = "2020-12-04 06:43:58.556385";
    
    Instant anInstant = isoFormatter.parse(aTimestampString, Instant::from);
    Instant anotherInstant = LocalDateTime.parse(anotherTimestampString, sqlTimestampFormatter)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toInstant();
    
    if (anInstant.isBefore(anotherInstant)) {
        System.out.println(aTimestampString + " is earlier");
    } else {
        System.out.println(anotherTimestampString + " is earlier");
    }
```

Output from this example is:

> 2020-12-03T05:35:59.398+0000 is earlier

The `+0000` in the former string above is an offset from UTC — an offset of 00 hours 00 minutes. Since it is zero, we know that the time is in UTC. I don’t know the time zone or UTC offset of the other string. You need to know, or you will get incorrect results. In the code above I have assumed that the other string is in UTC too.

### Don’t use Timestamp

> I tried the answer given here, and conversion did happen but the time
> was changed to `2020-12-03 11:05:59`

This is how confusing the `Timestamp` class is. You got the correct timestamp value. What happens when you *print* the `Timestamp` object, is that you are (implicitly or explicitly) calling its `toString` method. `Timestamp.toString()` confusingly uses the default time zone of your JVM for rendering the string. So if your timestamp is equal to 2020-12-03T05:35:59.398 UTC and your time zone is, say, Asia/Kolkata, then time is converted to Asia/Kolkata time zone and the string `2020-12-03 11:05:59` is returned and printed.

You have nothing good to use the old-fashioned `java.sql.Timestamp` class for. It was originally meant for transferring timestamp values with and without time zone to and from SQL databases. Since JDBC 4.2 we prefer `OffsetDateTime`, `Instant` and `LocalDateTime` for that purpose. So just forget about the `Timestamp` class.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there even a format for timestamp with wierd + in between 398+0000?

The `398` part is fraction-of-second (millisecond) while the `+0000` part is the zone offset part.

You can parse `2020-12-03T05:35:59.398+0000` into an `OffsetDateTime` using the format pattern, `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "2020-12-03T05:35:59.398+0000";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(text, formatter);
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-03T05:35:59.398Z
```

Check the [DateTimeFormatter documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to learn more about the letters used for formatting.

You can use `isBefore` and `isAfter` functions of `OffsetDateTime` to compare its two instances.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "2020-12-03T05:35:59.398+0000";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(text, formatter);
        OffsetDateTime odtNow = OffsetDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(odtNow.isBefore(odt));
        System.out.println(odtNow.isAfter(odt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
false
true
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Since [`java.sql.Timestamp` extends `java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), it is recommended to stop using that as well. However, for any reason, if you still want to use conversion between the modern and the legacy date-time API, use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) as the bridge.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "2020-12-03T05:35:59.398+0000";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(text, formatter);
        Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(instant.toEpochMilli());
        System.out.println(timestamp);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-03 05:35:59.398
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom `DateFormatter` for non-standard formats. Here is a working example for your use case.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;

import static java.time.temporal.ChronoField.*;

public class Main {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter INPUT_NON_STANDARD_FORMAT;

    static {
        INPUT_NON_STANDARD_FORMAT =
                new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                        .parseCaseInsensitive()
                        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
                        .appendLiteral('T')
                        .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
                        .appendLiteral(':')
                        .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
                        .optionalStart()
                        .appendLiteral(':')
                        .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
                        .optionalStart()
                        .appendLiteral('.')
                        .appendValue(MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
                        .appendLiteral("+0000")
                        .toFormatter();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String timestamp = "2020-12-03T05:35:59.398+0000";
        final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(timestamp, INPUT_NON_STANDARD_FORMAT);
        System.out.println(localDateTime.format(dateTimeFormatter));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
2020-12-03 05:35:59
```

Comment: Beware of hte case of format pattern letters. Uppercase `YYYY` will give you surprises around New Year.