# Kotlin - SimpleDateFormat parsing takes infinite time

Tags: android, datetime, debugging, kotlin, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse date string with `SimpleDateFormat` which never stops nor gives any exception. Please see the code below,

```
fun getDate(dateStr: String) {

    try {
        /** DEBUG dateStr = '2006-04-16T04:00:00Z' **/
        val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.ENGLISH)
        val mDate = formatter.parse(dateStr) // this never ends while debugging
    } catch (e: Exception){
        Logger.e("Error $e") // this never gets called either
    }
}
```

What can be the possible issue?

Note: I am using,

> Android Studio: 3.4.1, Kotlin version: 1.3.31, Min SDK: 23, Target SDK: 28, Compile SDK: 28

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2006-04-16T04:00:00Z" Its giving error

Comment: Its giving parse Exception directly .. Use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'` cause your date does not have value for ZONE .. Use `DateTime` API of Java 8 or some backport like `ThreeTenBP` for date operations..

Comment: There's a `'` missing before and after `Z`. Shouldn't it be like this: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'` in this code?

Comment: Possible sort of duplicate of [ISO 8601 String to Date/Time object in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941357/iso-8601-string-to-date-time-object-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use below function

```
fun getDate(dateStr: String) {
        try {
            /** DEBUG dateStr = '2006-04-16T04:00:00Z' **/
            val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH)
            val mDate = formatter.parse(dateStr) // this never ends while debugging
            Log.e("mDate", mDate.toString())
        } catch (e: Exception){
            Log.e("mDate",e.toString()) // this never gets called either
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wrong. The `Z` is an offset (of 0) form UTC and needs to be parsed as such (not as a literal), or you will get wrong times on the vast majority of JVMs.

Answer (score 2):

Your date format is incorrect. It should be as shown below

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

Notice the enclosing `'` with Z. You are missing that in your date format.

Comment: Interesting it solved my issue. But I wonder why there was no exception happens when I debugged. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad that I can help

Comment: Not correct. `Z` in the datetime string is an offset (of 0) from UTC and must be parsed as such (not as a literal), or you will get incorrect results (on the majority of JVMs).

Comment: Correction: it happens to work correctly on Android devices that have their time zone set to UTC. I believe they are not that many.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and my problem was that I was importing the wrong ParseException. You need to make sure you are importing the java.text parse exception.

Check the import code at the top of your file.

**CORRECT ParseException**

```
import java.text.ParseException
```

**INCORRECT ParseException**

```
import android.net.ParseException //Android example
```

Your date formats weren't lining up either, so of course that also needed to be fixed. But ideally you want the try/catch block to stop your program from crashing if the date strings are ever bad, so it's a good idea to test it with bad data.

Answer (score 0):

The timezone here actually is using ISO 8601 format.
To correctly parse this by Java SimpleDateFormat you should use the below pattern:
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"

Here X means time zone in ISO 8601 format.
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html