# How to format date to hours with SimpleDateFormat in Android?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I have the following date

```
2020-02-05T03:17:04.000Z
```

And I am trying to convert that to hour, and the result should be 22:17 but in my app I get 03:17

So, this is my code

```
public static String hour_visit(String hora){
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        Date convertedDate = new Date();
        String fecha_convert = "";
        try {
            convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(hora);
            SimpleDateFormat sdfnewformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            fecha_convert = sdfnewformat.format(convertedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fecha_convert;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Important:

In my web app I get 22:17 
My time zone is SouthAmerica

Comment: Isin't your code snippet from Swift? What code have you tried in Java/Kotlin?

Comment: let me change my code

Comment: nothings wrong with your code, at first format it was already in 03:17 and you just pull HH:mm which is still 03:17, double check your data.

Comment: I chan ge my code to android/java

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ISO 8601 String to Date/Time object in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941357/iso-8601-string-to-date-time-object-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Searching in all internet post I resolved my problem adding this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Answer (score 1):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

```
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");

    String instantString = "2020-02-05T03:17:04.000Z";

    Instant i = Instant.parse(instantString);
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = i.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    String fechaConvert = dateTime.format(timeFormatter);

    System.out.println("Converted time: " + fechaConvert);
```

I ran this snippet with my JVM time zone set to America/Guayaquil (Ecuador time) and got:

> Converted time: 22:17

(Many other time zones are used in different parts of South America.)

Your string is in the ISO 8601 format for an instant (a point in time). `Instant.parse()` expects this format, so we need no explicit formatter for parsing.

The date and time classes that you were trying to use, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`, are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. I frankly find it a lot nicer to work with.

### What went wrong in your code?

One of the many confusing traits of `SimpleDatFormat` is that it is happy only to parse as much of the given string as it can and tacitly ignore the rest. The `Z` in your string tells us that the date and time is in UTC, but your `SimpleDateFormat` ignores this crucial fact. It therefore parses the date and time as though they were in your own time zone. The second `SimpleDateFormat` instance then formats the wrong time back and gives you the time that was in the string, `03:17` (in this example).

As Andreas said, from API level 24 `SimpleDateFormat` can correctly parse the `Z`. On lower API levels it cannot. In contrast java.time has been backported and works on lower API levels too.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 0):

Your `SimpleDateFormat` pattern is missing an `X` at the end, so it correctly parses the `Z` at the end of the input.

*Test*

```
String hora = "2020-02-05T03:17:04.000Z";
Date convertedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX").parse(hora);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(convertedDate));
```

*Output (in US Eastern time zone)*

```
22:17
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since pattern `X` requires [API Level 24+ in Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat#date-and-time-patterns), and patterns `Z` and `z` don't support the `Z` zone suffix in the date string, the alternative is to force input to have `Z` and force parser to use UTC time zone for parsing.

*Test*

```
String hora = "2020-02-05T03:17:04.000Z";

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(hora);

SimpleDateFormat sdfnewformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
System.out.println(sdfnewformat.format(convertedDate));
```

*Output (in US Eastern time zone)*

```
22:17
```

Comment: @Israel Ahh... `X` requires API Level 24+

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Put your time in a string then split it

```
String full_dat_tym_buy = "2020-02-05T03:17:04.000Z";
String[] spiltby_T_buy = full_dat_tym_buy.split("T");
date_buy = spiltby_T_buy[0].trim();
String tym_wid_Z_buy = spiltby_T_buy[1].trim();
String spiltby_Dot1_buy = tym_wid_Z_buy.replace(".000Z", "");
replace_tym_buy = spiltby_Dot1_buy.replace(":", "-");
Log.e("replacetime", replace_tym_buy);
```

then format your date using time zone
try

```
{

String FinalDate = getOnlyDate( replace_tym_buy);
Log.e("difference", String.valueOf(FinalDate));


} catch (Exception exception) {

}
```

Add this method in your class

```
private String getOnlyDate(String OurDate_) {
String chk_date = OurDate_;
Log.e("datededde", chk_date);
try {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm-ss");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date value = formatter.parse(OurDate_);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"); //this format changeable
    Log.e("time: ", TimeZone.getDefault() + "");
    dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    OurDate_ = dateFormatter.format(value);
    Log.e("OurDate_", OurDate_);
} catch (Exception e) {
    OurDate_ = chk_date;
}
return OurDate_;

}
```