# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using SimpleDateFomat vs JodaTime?

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I am creating a button in Android, minSdkVersion="8" and targetSdkVersion="17", for the user to select the date and time. With a onClick (selectDate) method as follows:

```
public void selectDate(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
}

public static void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    m_selectDateBtn.setText(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
}

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, m_year, m_month,
                m_day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        populateSetDate(year, month, day);
    }
}
```

After looking at a few other questions on stackoverflow of how to parse the date text that will be stored in the button:

[String to Date/Time object in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941357/string-to-date-time-object-in-android)

[How can I recognize the Zulu time zone in Java DateUtils.parseDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424522/how-can-i-recognize-the-zulu-time-zone-in-java-dateutils-parsedate)

**Question:** I am wondering what are the advantages and disadvantages of using SimpleDateFormat vs [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)? Or what other Date class would you recommend for what I want to do?

[Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) does have some reason why to use Joda Time, but I do not know much about Date classes to know how true the statements are.

Comment: The real question is - which one(s) work for you. That is, which one(s) do exactly as you need in the easiest/cleanest manner. If it doesn't work, will the other approach?

Comment: @pst good question. This is more of what I am trying to figure out and as I probably have users use my app, maybe I'll find out more about what will work and what will not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### SimpleDateFormat

**Advantages**:

- Easy to use. I use it all the time.
- No additional installation necessary.
- Updates will come automatically with Android SDK updates.

**Example**:

```
final Date curDateTime = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mma, MMM. dd");
String text = formatter.format(curDateTime);
```

**Disadvantages**:

- [Date, Calendar, DateFormat, SQL, Timestamp, Millis issues](http://mestachs.wordpress.com/tag/jodatime/)

---

### JodaTime

**Advantages**:

- Similar usage across multiple Java platforms.
- Supports additional calendars such as Buddhist and Ethiopic.
- Self-reported better performance.

**Disadvantages**:

- Requires installation of package and perhaps updates from Joda.org.

---

### Conclusion

For all date/time formatting I have needed, I am happy with `SimpleDateFormat` and will continue using it. For my needs, there is no justified reason of which I am aware for switching to another library.

**See Also**: [Alternatives to SimpleDateFormat for date parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412205/alternatives-to-simpledateformat-for-date-parsing)

Comment: thanks! marking yours as the correct answer for now